# I/O methods in C

Tags: c, performance

I am looking for various ways of reading/writing data from stdin/stdout. Currently I know about scanf/printf, getchar/putchar and gets/puts. Are there any other ways of doing this? Also I am interesting in knowing that which one is most efficient in terms of Memory and Space.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Read a book, such as the C programming Language. And I/O operations are not normally CPU bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stdio is designed to be fairly efficient no matter which way you prefer to read data. If you need to do character-by-character reads and writes, they usually expand to macros which just access the buffer except when it's full/empty. For line-by-line text io, use `puts`/`fputs` and `fgets`. (But **NEVER** use `gets` because there's no way to control how many bytes it will read!) The `printf` family (e.g. `fprintf`) is of course extremely useful for text because it allows you to skip constructing a temporary buffer in memory before writing (and thus lets you avoid thinking about all the memory allocation, overflow, etc. issues). `fscanf` tends to be much less useful, but mostly because it's difficult to use. If you study the documentation for `fscanf` well and learn how to use `%[`, `%n`, and the numeric specifiers, it can be very powerful!

For large blocks of text (e.g. loading a whole file into memory) or binary data, you can also use the `fread` and `fwrite` functions. You should always pass 1 for the size argument and the number of bytes to read/write for the count argument; otherwise it's impossible to tell from the return value how much was successfully read or written.

If you're on a reasonably POSIX-like system (pretty much anything) you can also use the lower-level io functions `open`, `read`, `write`, etc. These are **NOT** part of the C standard but part of POSIX, and non-POSIX systems usually provide the same functions but possibly with slightly-different behavior (for example, file descriptors may not be numbered sequentially 0,1,2,... like POSIX would require).

Answer (score 3):

```
fgets() 
fputs()
read()
write()
```

And others, details can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/

As per your time question take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound

Comment: `read` and `write` are not part of C but rather POSIX functions (also present on most other systems, but with mildly different behavior).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for immediate-mode type stuff don't forget about [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) (more applicable on the *NIX side but also available on Windows)